# Do ship captains have the authority to solemnize marriages?

Tags: marriage

I have seen some works of fiction portraying marriage ceremonies happening on ships, officiated by sea captains (such as a famous scene in the Disney movie *At World's End*).

Is this a tradition outside fictional works? Or at least based on some tradition? Can ship captains legally marry people aboard a ship?

Comment: See https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6612/can-a-ships-captain-legally-marry-people

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the flag the ship is flying. In my country (sweden) a ship captain could marry people, but the authority was removed as unnecessary around 2000. I Wonder what the US rules are?

Comment: Almost no passenger ships fly under a U.S. flag. Captains of U.S. Navy and Coast Guard ships do not have that authority as a general rule.

Answer (score 1):

### No, and they never did

It’s a Hollywood [myth](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/02/fashion/weddings/a-marriage-at-sea-get-me-rewrite.html) and always has been.

Of course, there is nothing stopping any given ship’s captain from also being a qualified marriage celebrant and that person could marry people. However, getting and maintaining a ship master’s ticket is a full time job on its own so very few do.

Comment: Allthough that maybe true today, it certainly was not in the past. One of the tasks of a Master of a UK registered vessel is definded in present day UK legislation: [Merchant Shipping Act 1894 Section 253 (1)(viii)](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/57-58/60/section/253/enacted): **Any marriage which takes place on board with the date thereof, and the names and ages of the parties.**

Comment: @MarkJohnson that requires that they record marriages, not conduct them